# Unresolved references to an array and to simple_spinner_item layout

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, resources, spinner

My layout includes

```
    <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerCategory"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/lblCategory"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/lblCategory"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/lblCategory" />
```

Strings.xml

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">nearby</string>

<string-array name="categories">
    <item>Any</item>
    <item>Church</item>
    <item>NT</item>
</string-array>
```

MainActivity.kt (only partially completed, so far)

```
package com.example.nearby

import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Spinner
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.temp_layout.*


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    var mCategoryFilter = ""

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.temp_layout)
        getInputs()
    }

    fun getInputs() {
        if (!txtLat.toString().equals("")) {
            var temp = txtLat.text.toString().toDouble()
            mLatitude = temp.toFloat()
        }
        if (!txtLong.toString().equals("")) {
            mLongitude = txtLong.text.toString().toFloat()
        }

        val spinner: Spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinnerCategory)
        val adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(
            this,
            R.array.categories, R.layout.simple_spinner_item
        )
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
        spinner.adapter = adapter

    }
}
```

Android Studio marks the following as "unresolved references"

- the word "array" in R.array.categories
- "simple_spinner_item"
- "simple_spinner_dropdown_item"

How do I resolve these references?

**Solution**
Mike M's suggestion that I use the Invalidate Caches/Restart option seems to have solved the reference to "array".
The simple_spinner layout references need to be prefixed with android (with **lower case a**), as in android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item.

Beware, if using Android Studio's automatic conversion of Java code to Kotlin. It seems to have been this that deleted "android" from the layout references.

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project, and if that doesn't do it, try Invalidate Caches/Restart. Recent Android Studio versions are having trouble with newly created resources, for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I used the "Clean Project" then the "Rebuild Project" options from the Build menu. After the rebuild finished a Build Output window opened listing the two still unresolved references to the simple_spinner layouts. The word array is still underlined in the code.

Comment: I've now used Invalidate Caches and Restart from the File menu, and have clicked the Terminate process box. Android Studio closed and restarted automatically and the errors have gone. However, when I tried to run the app numerous errors appeared, the first of which stated that AppCompatActivity was unresolved! Gradel Build the ran again and the original unresolved references reappeared!

Comment: Yeah, that's becoming more and more common. It's a real pain to have to restart your IDE just to get those working. Anyhoo, this is what we could classify as non-reproducible, so you can just delete this question, when you get a chance. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Comment: Mike M Unfortunately, after trying to run the app, the errors have reappeared. To clarify: there is now no unresolved reference reported for the word array in R.array.categories but the two simple_spinner layout references are again unresolved.

Comment: I had copied and pasted the spinner code into MainActivity from a tutorial, and accepted the automatic conversion to Kotlin. It appears that this conversion deleted the references to android at the start of android.R.layout.simple ... I had already tried inserting Android (with a capital A) but that didn't work. I now realise that all I needed to do was use lower case instead! (NB lower case a, but capital R !!!) So, the upshot is that the Invallidate Caches/Restart seems to be what fixed the reference to array and reinstatement of android have fixed the errors. Thanks for your help.